# VS2008 C# Exceptions with methods invoked by reflection

Tags: c#, debugging

If I invoke a method which does something illegal, the debugger will stop at the line of code, in that method, which threw the exception

If I use reflection to call a method via Invoke  and that method throws an exception, the debugger stops on line where the method was called via reflection and not in the faulty method itself

How do I change this, and have the debugger stop on the line of code in error in regardless of how the method was invoked?

The code is built in Debug

Answer (score 3):

Check the "Thrown" box for the particular exception -- the debugger will stop where the exception is thrown, before it's caught (and translated) by the Invoke layer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a debug version of the assembly?
If not, the debugger cannot locate the source of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you know this signature of method called by reflection. You can create a delegate.

If you have the class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private string GetSomeText() { return DateTime.Now.ToString(); }
}
```

you can create a delegate:

```
delegate string DlgGetSomeText();
```

and then create a delegate's instance with referenco to concrete method:

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass();
DlgGetSomeText dlg = (DlgGetSomeText)Delegate.CreateDelegate( cls.GetType(), cls, "GetSomeText" );
string result = dlg();
```

If you will use a delegate, the reflection calling will not be used, so your problem will nod appear.

Comment: Thank you but it seems quite a bit of work just to have the debugger stop where it should!

Comment: Yes I know. But I doesn't develop VS :).
The next advantage is the performance. Creating a delegate is much more faster than calling with reflection.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; very helpful.  The use of delegate in this way also eases the passing of parameters -- in code one merely calls the delegate as if a function pointer without needing to create an array of objects for parameters.